# Posting Images to instagram through website

Tags: android, wordpress, instagram, instagram-api

I`m working on a wordpress project where client wants poll voting by its users and after completion results will be displayed on website and instagram of user account.
Now, i know instagram does not provide sharing option, so we are thinking of making something like https://later.com/

They provide scheduling service where image get uploaded to there android app from where it pushes it to instagram app.

Can we get this service from market (an app which can push image to instagram). if not any suggestions on how to proceed on this project will be helpful.
Thank you

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Will there be an Android App for your service?

Comment: Initially we are trying to do it without android app, if that doesn`t work we have to make an android app.

Comment: You will not be able to post images to Instagram without interfacing with the Instagram app. Instagrams API does not allow the creation of new posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Their is one way by which You can post your voting images or result(images) to Instagram  through admin panel. visit https://github.com/swapnil1079/WordPress-to-Instagram ! take the code from here upload it on the server and use it with your instagram user name and password. and create a post with feature image, it will automatically post on your instagram account. you can  also use this with your custom post type.

Comment: Your code is working fine, but it is for a single instagram account, can we make something which can be used for multiple accounts.

Comment: You can not use this api for marketing purpose otherwise instagram can block your accounts to post images. and if multiple user will post number of images from a single site then instagram API will restrict you.but still i will check for a solution if any possibilities.